# Getting no response while verify both inbound and outbound rules present in the excel sheet using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am preparing one PowerShell script which needs to check Both inbound and outbound rules are on the same designsheet (excelsheet). I am using below code for checking the inbound and outbound rules present in the excel sheet with column name  as "description" and value as "inbound" and "outbound". The code is executing without any errors but it is directly giving the output as "Both inbound and outbound rules are missing in the 'Description' column" even though the inbound and outbound information is present under description column. I have tried multiple ways but still facing the issue. Can some one please help me to resolve this issue.

```
code:
# Load the Excel file
$designSheet = "/homedir/lokesh/NSG_Rules.xlsx"
$excel = Import-Excel -Path $designSheet
# Check if both inbound and outbound rules exist in the 'Description' column

$inboundRuleExists = $excel | Where-Object { $_.Description -eq 'Inbound' }
$outboundRuleExists = $excel | Where-Object { $_.Description -eq 'Outbound' }

if ($inboundRuleExists -and $outboundRuleExists) {
    Write-Host "Both inbound and outbound rules are present in the 'Description' column"
} elseif (-not $inboundRuleExists -and -not $outboundRuleExists) {
    Write-Host "Both inbound and outbound rules are missing in the 'Description' column"
} elseif (-not $inboundRuleExists) {
    Write-Host "Inbound rule is missing in the 'Description' column"
} else {
    Write-Host "Outbound rule is missing in the 'Description' column"
}

Output:
PS /homedir/lokesh> ./NSGRulesvalidation.ps1 
Both inbound and outbound rules are missing in the 'Description' column
PS /homedir/lokesh>
```

Comment: Are you sure the column name is `Description` and there are no spaces or other invisible characters in that column cell? Personally, I would use `[bool]$inboundRuleExists = @($excel | Where-Object { $_.Description -eq 'Inbound' }).Count`, same for `$outboundRuleExists`, so you have either $true or $false values to check against

Comment: Excel Worksheet has a dollar sign at beginning of name which indicates the worksheet is a system table.  You are missing the worksheet name.  The variable $designSheet is the workbook name.  Try : $inboundRuleExists = $excel.Worksheets[0] | Where-Object { $_.Description -eq 'Inbound' }

Comment: Thank you Theo and jdweng for resolving my issue